# Sending iOS push notification notification over HTTP2 using .p12 developer certificate

Tags: openssl, apple-push-notifications, http2, p12

So I am trying to convert apple developer certificate for push notification to .pem file. Later I want to use that file to send apple push notifications over HTTP2 like this:

```
1. openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -in aps_dev.p12 -out aps_dev.pem
2. curl -v -d '{"aps":{"alert":"hello"}}' --http2 --cert aps_dev.pem https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/31abcb1367eaa30abc4e293f19a12aeabcdd25b04dca1234caa594b10946a21
```

While I can send the notification to the device. What I'm trying to understand is whether:

1. If it is a HTTP2 request is certificate is sent to APNS.
2. OR a secure socket is created using the certificate between and then a HTTP2 request is written over it?

I can see system opens some sockets after the call but I'm not sure if the socket is between my system and APNs server.